# What to do first when porting library

Tags: java, ruby, jar, porting

I want to access Java library within Ruby, in example Kafka already give jar for every operation, what things I need to do if I want to use it from Ruby?

Like maybe I just need to run shell command to run the Jar within Ruby, or do I need to port the library in Ruby? If it comes down to porting the library, how to do that too?

Thank you in advance

PS: The Java, Ruby, or Kafka are just examples. What I need to know is the big picture how to porting a library. Of course if you add some code example too I'll be more than happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Aetherus that the fastest and most convenient way is to use JRuby. However I believe there other options than *communicating with external Java processes*. What to choose probably depends on what code you want to call. I see at least two other options.

- Wrap the Java code you want to call in a main program and call it on the command line. This will be slow since Java needs to start and that takes forever but may be a fast way forward in some cases.
- Call the Java code from C code that you compile with your Ruby. This will still need to load the JVM but you could probably make it happen only once. I found an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI) outlining how to get around doing it with JNI.

Both these paths will probably cause you a lot of pain but if it is important to stay on MRI it may be worth the trip. Have fun!

Comment: I guess the first way will be easier to start with

Answer (score 0):

With JRuby, you can import the jar file, then include the classes you need in that jar:

```
require 'java'
require '/path/to/your.jar'

include_class 'com.really.long.ClassName'
```

But with Ruby implementations other than JRuby, you have no choice but to communicate with external java processes (through socket, IPC, kill, ...).